# How to get course progress in Moodle 4?

Tags: moodle

I will leave my question below. My problem is that I want to obtain the progress that is seen when you enter the system interface and the user sees if they have 50/100% of the progress of the course, that is the progress that I am looking to achieve and add in my query.

I have Moodle 4.0, I leave you my question to see if you can give me some ideas.

```
   SELECT u.id         as user_id,
       u.firstname,
       u.lastname,
       c.id         as course_id,
       c.fullname   as corusename,
       act.id       as activity_id,
       act.itemname as activity,
       grades.finalgrade as activity_grade


    FROM mdl_course AS c
    /*CONEXION DE CURSO A USUARIO*/
         INNER JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid
         INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id
         INNER JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
    /*FIN CONEXION DE CURSO A USUARIO*/
    /*CONEXION USUARIO A ACTIVIDADES*/
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_items act ON act.courseid = c.id AND act.itemmodule = 'scorm'
    /*FIN CONEXION USUARIO A ACTIVIDADES*/
    /*CONEXION ACTIVIDADES Y CALIFICACIONES*/
    INNER JOIN mdl_grade_grades grades ON grades.itemid = act.id and grades.userid = u.id
    /*FIN ACTIVIDADES Y CALIFICACIONES*/

     WHERE c.id in (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26)

    ORDER BY act.courseid
```

| Activity | Grade | Progres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acti1 | 85 | 30% |
| acti2 | 100 | 35% |

Comment: Anything not working with the given query? Is this a PHP or a Moodle problem? You haven't shared any such code

Comment: "I want" is neither a question or a problem statement. What have you researched and attempted so far? Where are you stuck in achieving the stated goal? See also [ask].

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of "user sees if they have 50/100% of the progress of the course" - is it the completion status block?